# System.Windows.Application.OnLoadCompleted never reached

Tags: wpf

Hello I am trying to handle the [`Application.LoadCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.onloadcompleted.aspx) event but it's never triggered.

Instead I am seeing the MainWindow.

I tried attaching the event by either xaml, or directly by overriding the OnLoadCompleted method of the Application class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does your MainWindow contain a Frame?

If you read the text for [the event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.loadcompleted.aspx) (not the On... method), it says

> Occurs when content that was navigated
>   to by a navigator in the application
>   has been loaded

I just tested on a Form with a Frame and the event fires just fine.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible you're using the wrong event for what you want.

If you are just trying to initialize your application - perhaps to set up global messaging handlers or you can use `OnStartup`.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    static App()
    {
        DispatcherHelper.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeMVVM();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be simply that you're attaching the event too late. i.e. after the loaded event has already fired. Show us the code...

Comment: He does say he's tried overriding OnLoadCompleted, which couldn't be done 'too late'